# Install and build Boost library in Linux

Tags: linux, boost

I'm following the [Boost Getting Started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) article.
I've installed it with Bjam and I could see include files and library files (.a, .so).

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    boost::regex pat( "^Subject: (Re: |Aw: )*(.*)" );
}
```

If I build above code using this command

```
g++ -I./boost/include -L./boost/lib -lboost_regex-gcc43-mt -static -o test_boost2 test_boost2.cc
```

I get this error:

```
/tmp/ccJFVVid.o: In function `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)':
    test_boost2.cc:(.text._ZN5boost11basic_regexIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE6assignEPKcS7_j[boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)]+0x22): undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It was working okay under my Windows machine.

What's wrong?

gcc version 4.3.2 (Debian 4.3.2-1.1)

Linux xxxxxxxx 2.6.26-1-686 #1 SMP Fri Mar 13 18:08:45 UTC 2009 i686 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the problem! g++ command problem! :( sorry.
If I move back -l option to the end of the line, it does not complain more :)

Answer (score 17):

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-regex-dev
```

Don't bother installing from source where a much more intelligent system can do better.

To compile, just use

```
g++ -lboost_regex boost.cpp -o boost
```

To get list of available package names (more parts of boost):

```
apt-cache search libboost | grep -- -dev
```

**Dislaimer**: I assume you use Debian since that's what your GCC version reports.

Comment: It works! But how should I do if I want to install the latest version of Boost(1.39)? Because what I really want to use is Boost.Asio library. :)

Comment: If you're using lenny you can use 'libboost1.35-dev', if you're using squeeze, there's 'libboost1.38-dev'. There's also the standalone version of asio, 'libasio-dev'. The versions in lenny are pretty old though.

Comment: linked libraries should be at the end of the compile should they not? Therefore it would be:                                                                                
         g++ boost.cpp -o boost  -lboost_regex

Answer (score 2):

Your

```
-L./boost/lib
```

seems suspect. When you build Boost, the libraries are put into stage/lib directory. Also, the default build process does not create static libraries, so you probably better take `-static` off the command line. If that does not fix the problem, I suggest you follow the steps at [my blog](http://vladimir_prus.blogspot.com/2009/06/linking-101.html) to troubleshoot this.

Comment: After I compiled regex separately and use its result, just same error.

g++ -I./boost_1_39_0 ./boost_1_39_0/libs/regex/build/gcc/libboost_regex-gcc-1_38.a -o test_boost2 test_boost2.cc

Comment: g++ -I./boost_1_39_0 -o test_boost2 test_boost2.cc ./boost_1_39_0/libs/regex/build/gcc/libboost_regex-gcc-1_38.a

^ this works!!!!!!

Comment: This is because for static libraries, the position you specify them on the linker's command line matters. Again, see the blog post.